# How to download file on submit which had been created on the same time in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to download csv file on **submit button click** which had been created on the same time in ***PHP*** ?

Comment: be more specific, maybe also include some code... alternatively i can show you a quick javascript solution on clientside...to create csv on the fly

Comment: it you can open that file url in new tab. this will download file. or you can do as it suggested in your anwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a content type header to suggest to the browser that the resulting page has to be downloaded:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');

// Hint the filename
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="whateveryoulike.csv"');

// echo the contents here
echo $csvString;
```

Comment: Thanks Erik. It helps. I have finally used something like this $file = "$result.csv";

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
}